# Append data in spring batch

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-batch

I'd like to know how to specify that I want the data output by the second job **being appended** to the data output by the first job:

job1 ---> *data 1* ---> Output XML file

job2 ---> *data 2* ---> SAME Output XML file

But when I open the output XML I find only *data 2*

I'd like to find this:

---

Output file

---

*data1*

*data2*

How can I configure this in spring batch. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Same requirement to append XML, any solution ?

Comment: Same requirement here!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share configurations for reference.

```
<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:outputs/test.xml" />
        <property name="encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
        <property name="version" value="1.0" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="record" />

        <!-- TRUE means, that output file will be overwritten if exists - default is TRUE -->
        <property name="overwriteOutput" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

If you set `<property name="overwriteOutput" value="false" />` then if `test.xml` already present in the `outputs` directory, then it will give the error if you doing restart of the job. If job is not restarted, then it will append to the XML file.

Answer (score -1):

I presume you're using the `StaxEventItemWriter`.  There is a property `overwriteOutput` which is set to true.  If this value is set to true, it will overwrite the file if it exists.  Set it to false, and it will append to the existing file (this flag is ignored on restarts).  You can read more about this flag in the javadoc here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemWriter.html#setOverwriteOutput-boolean-

Comment: When I set this property to false an exception raises org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: File already exists: [C:\Users\XXX\xml\outputs\DonneesFactureFromDB.xml] THEN a nullPointerException

Comment: Yes I'm using org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter

Comment: Any other idea please ?

Comment: @SindaMOKADDEM did you solve this problem?